# secure connection to imap from java by storing key for password encryption

Tags: java, security

Is there any way to connect  from java application to IMAP server without storing password?? Though i explored and couldn't find any way. So I am encrypting the password with a key and decided to divide key in parts and store in different place- database and some session. Any other way?

Answer (score 0):

What authentication functions can be used depends on the server. The client has to use what the server provides.

By default the authentication mechanism that every IMAP server supports in plain authentication using username/password which of course means that you have to store the password.

There are other authentication mechanisms like Kerberos - see [RFC1731](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1731) but as far as I know most servers do not support this.

On the other had there are servers that support OAuth2 authentication via IMAP, but I am not sure if this is really something standardized. As far as I know it is for example used by [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth) and [Google](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/xoauth2-protocol). Yahoo even seems to require oAuth for IMAP but I wasn't able to find a link to Yahoo describing this.

Comment: I do not want to use Oauth2.. is there any safe way to store key?

Comment: @Oauth2 is the best way to not having to store a password. Of course you then have to store the token(s) securely but from a security perspective everything is better than a user password because the tokens can be changed at any time.

Comment: thanks robert, but for my application i have to deal with some another server for which Oauth2 will not work. i have to keep password, i would really appreciate if u can help me with any scheme to securely store the key which i can use for encrypting the password and can later use for decryption while connection to the store. As mentioned I thought of splitting the key, but the only places i can think of is Database or session. Can u please suggest some more secure way?? Thanks..

Comment: Sorry but I won't answer you how to securely store a password because without another user based password or a special hardware or OS functionality there is no security. Everything you can do is obscurity. Please read the dozen of questions and answers here on stackoverflow regarding secure password storage in client applications.